# Pandas DataFrame from WB WDI data: combine year columns into "year" variable and merge rows

Tags: python, pivot, pandas, time-series, tabular

I have a dataset (.tsv file) with the following columns. (It's the World Bank's new WDI all-in all-time [single-download dataset](http://databank.worldbank.org/data/download/WDI_csv.zip). Nice!)

```
country countrycode varname 1960 1961 1962
afghanistan AFG GDP 5.6 5.7 5.8
afghanistan AFG Gini .77 .78 .75
afghanistan AFG educ 8.1 8.2 8.3
afghanistan AFG pop 888 889 890
albania ALB GDP 6.6 6.7 6.8
albania ALB Gini .45 .46 .47
albania ALB educ 6.2 6.3 6.4
albania ALB pop 777 778 779
```

I need a pandas DataFrame with  ['GDP','Gini','edu','pop'] as columns, along with ['country', 'countrycode', 'year'].  So the values for "year" are currently columns!
And I'd like there to be only one row for each country-year combination.

For instance, the columns and first row would be

```
country countrycode year GDP Gini educ pop
afghanistan AFG 1960 5.6 .77 8.1 888
```

This seems like some complex pivot or opposite-of-"melt", but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [59]: df
Out[59]:
       country countrycode varname    1960    1961    1962
0  afghanistan         AFG     GDP    5.60    5.70    5.80
1  afghanistan         AFG    Gini    0.77    0.78    0.75
2  afghanistan         AFG    educ    8.10    8.20    8.30
3  afghanistan         AFG     pop  888.00  889.00  890.00
4      albania         ALB     GDP    6.60    6.70    6.80
5      albania         ALB    Gini    0.45    0.46    0.47
6      albania         ALB    educ    6.20    6.30    6.40
7      albania         ALB     pop  777.00  778.00  779.00

In [60]: df = df.set_index(['country', 'countrycode', 'varname'])

In [61]: df.columns.name = 'year'

In [62]: df.stack().unstack('varname')
Out[62]:
varname                       GDP  Gini  educ  pop
country     countrycode year
afghanistan AFG         1960  5.6  0.77   8.1  888
                        1961  5.7  0.78   8.2  889
                        1962  5.8  0.75   8.3  890
albania     ALB         1960  6.6  0.45   6.2  777
                        1961  6.7  0.46   6.3  778
                        1962  6.8  0.47   6.4  779
```

The latter is a frame with a MutliIndex, you can do reset_index to move the MultiIndex to regular columns.

Comment: Magic. Thank you. What does one need to do for that to become easy to figure out? I'm getting older, or this language is subtle. I've (sorry) added another answer below, using the actual WDI variable names. If I can, and if you want to incorporate it into yours, I'll delete it.

Comment: There are sveral stack/unstack examples in the docs http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-stacking-and-unstacking (same page also demos pivot and melt). An extra answer is just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Group your `DataFrame` by `country` and `countrycode` and then apply your own function:

```
In [13]: def f(df):
   ....:     del df['country']
   ....:     del df['countrycode']
   ....:     df = df.set_index('varname')
   ....:     df.index.name = None
   ....:     df = df.T
   ....:     df.index.name = 'year'
   ....:     return df
   ....: 

In [14]: df.groupby(['country', 'countrycode']).apply(f).reset_index()
Out[14]: 
       country countrycode  year  GDP  Gini  educ  pop 
0  afghanistan         AFG  1960  5.6  0.77   8.1  888 
1  afghanistan         AFG  1961  5.7  0.78   8.2  889 
2  afghanistan         AFG  1962  5.8  0.75   8.3  890 
3      albania         ALB  1960  6.6  0.45   6.2  777 
4      albania         ALB  1961  6.7  0.46   6.3  778 
5      albania         ALB  1962  6.8  0.47   6.4  779
```

Comment: Also clever. And subtle. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suggesting that @Wouter may put this in his (accepted) answer, as it uses the actual names from the WDI data, and makes it more cut and paste for someone else using them. Sorry -- I'm sure this isn't the right way to communicate this...

For any variables that you want to keep/use, just give them a name in this dict:

```
WDIconversions={"Year":'year',
"YearCode":'',
"Country Name":'country_name_wb',
"Country Code":'countryCode_ISO3_WB',
"Inflation, consumer prices (annual %)":'',
"Inflation, GDP deflator (annual %)":'',
"GDP per capita, PPP (constant 2005 international $)":'GDPpc',
"Firms with female participation in ownership (% of firms)":'',
"Investment in energy with private participation (current US$)":'',
"Investment in telecoms with private participation (current US$)":'',
"Investment in transport with private participation (current US$)":'',
"Investment in water and sanitation with private participation (current US$)":'',
"Labor participation rate, female (% of female population ages 15+)":'',
"Labor participation rate, male (% of male population ages 15+)":'',
"Labor participation rate, total (% of total population ages 15+)":'',
"Ratio of female to male labor participation rate (%)":'',
"Life expectancy at birth, female (years)":'',
"Life expectancy at birth, male (years)":'',
"Life expectancy at birth, total (years)":'lifeExpectancy',
"Population, total":'nat_pop',
"GINI index":'GiniWB',
} # etc etc etc 
dfW=pd.read_table(WBDrawfile) 
df = dfW.set_index(['Country Name','Country Code','Indicator Name'])
del df['Indicator Code']
df.columns.name = 'year'
df=df.stack().unstack('Indicator Name')
df=df[[kk for kk,ii in WDIconversions.items() if ii and kk in df]].reset_index().rename(columns=WDIconversions)
```

That results in:

```
 df
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 12983 entries, 0 to 12982
Data columns:
country_name_wb        12983  non-null values
countryCode_ISO3_WB    12983  non-null values
year                   12983  non-null values
GiniWB                 845  non-null values
nat_pop                12601  non-null values
GDPpc                  6292  non-null values
educPrimary            4949  non-null values
lifeExpectancy         11077  non-null values
dtypes: float64(5), object(3)
```